# Dynamically generate Google map LatLng from database in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have search the net but as ASP.NET MVC syntaxing has changed so much I am at a loss never mind that I am still a noob at MVC.

I am using ASP.NET 4.5.1 and MVC 5.

I have the following LatLng fields in the Location table in the DB: Lat, Lng

I am not sure how to go about getting those co-ords out form there and putting them into this format:

```
//Co-ords for map polygon
var mapCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.91353, 175.47578),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.95565, 175.53483),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.96309, 175.53603),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.96944, 175.52556),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.9717, 175.50633),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.97321, 175.49363),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8898, 175.41553),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.86936, 175.40866),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.86728, 175.43612),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-36.87668, 175.45054)
        ];
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already, you should use an ORM like Entity Framework for the data layer. That will take care of pulling the data from the Location table and providing it as a Location object for you.

Then you have multiple choices on how to set your mapCoords var, but one way is to perform a foreach (var location in Locations){} to iterate through and set the data for the mapCoords. You'll have the latitude and longitude as location.Lat and location.Lng.